# Viz.json-based map will not show Line polygons

Tags: carto, carto-js

We are using a visualization and I importing it via a `cartodb.createVisualization`. Most of the tables work fine and the whole visualization works within the web console. However, we have one table which has a `Line` geometry. This geometry displays in the web console and appears in the website, but breaks when I use the `.setSQL` method. We have a large number of rows in this table (60k+). Often, the "loader" will hang. When I attempt to show this layer, the `png` GETs come back completely empty (transparent). Similarly, the `grid.json` requests show up empty, even when I have infowidnows I would expect to be populated with data. I am not getting any 404 errors.

When I request rows via the SQL API (like through `sql.execute`) the rows come back as expected. Also, I have tried using this visualization in my own website and in the example [here](https://gist.github.com/javisantana/7b817fda1e7511c451c7), to make sure that it's not my mistake, but the problem is the same.

I don't know if it's related, but calling `.show()` on this sublayer also fails. Calling `.show()` on any of the sublayers will lead to unexpected behavior if I do it repeatedly (like instead of showing the correct sublayer, it shows a different sublayer that was hidden.)

Edit:  This geometry displays in the web console and appears in the website, but breaks when I use the `.setSQL` method. We have a large number of rows in this table (60k+ rows).

**Update:**  Cut the table from ~60k rows to ~14k and things are working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

[I have done an example](http://bl.ocks.org/juanignaciosl/368db08219ba7f8a4955), based in the one you said didn't work], and it works: it displays the line and infowindow, at least in my browser. Maybe I did not understood your problem?

Comment: See edit, the problem occurs when I use `lineLayer.setSQL`.

Comment: I see. With that example I certainly get a "Uncaught Error: sql is read-only in NamedMaps" error if I attempt to use setSQL. Check whether that's your problem. There's a good reason for that behaviour, you can read it here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/87869/cartodb-sql-query-of-public-visualization-of-a-private-table . If I use a public table I can call setSQL as normal. Check this code: https://gist.github.com/juanignaciosl/368db08219ba7f8a4955

Comment: The problem went away when I cut the number of rows down to ~14k.